# Highlighting and Deselection of UINavigationController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

Most iPhone apps that I use have a very subtle but slick behavior when using a navigation flow.  When you return to the previous view, the selected item immediately deselects so you get a brief un-highlighting.  This tells the user which item they just edited/viewed.

My problem is that my own application does not exhibit this behavior.  I set it up in xcode 4.2 using mostly segues, but with some code behind.

I've narrowed it down to the fact that i am using reloadData in viewWillAppear.  But I need to reload this on return from a modal which I use to add items to the list.

How/where should I be reloading my list so that it includes the new item but does not stop the deselect/highlight pattern from working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to reload this on return from a modal which I use to add items to the list.

Reloading the entire table is conceptually simple, but a better solution might be to call `-insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to add the new rows to the table. That should allow the deselection animation to proceed normally, and you may also get a nice animation as new rows are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the deselection uses the default animation duration of `0.25f` so why not in `viewDidAppear:` use:

```
[self.tableView performSelector:@(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25f];
```

I'm sure there will be a better way though

Answer (score 0):

Do these steps.

Declare an int value "selectedCell" in .h file and assign -1 in viewDidLoad: method.
In

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method, do

```
if (indexPath.row==selectedCell){
cell.selected=YES;
}
```

And in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method, do

```
selectedCell=indexPath.row;
```

It will make the selected row highlighted always.